# can I connect my acoustic electric guitar to a home stereo amplifier and play thru the stereo

Tags: practice

Can I connect my acoustic electric guitar to a stereo integrated amplifier and play through my stereo system?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, and no. Stereo speakers are designed for efficiency and sensitivity, whereas instrument speakers are designed with 'shock loads' in mind. It will work, as long as you keep the volume low. The question is, how low is 'low'?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but the gain structure of the amp circuit is not as high as a lot of music instrument amps so you might want to try a preamp between the instrument and the stereo. Also a Y cable can get both sides of the stereo happening. As with a lot of things in music, you may wish to experiment with it before you try it publicly.